# Unlock HSQLdb after exception

Tags: java, hsqldb

I am trying to make a simple self contained java application with Hsqldb database built into it. I've encountered a problem, where after an exception occurred the connection (?) remains, the lock file is present and used by java runtime and as such - can not be deleted manually.

**My question is** how can I programmatically detect the database is locked and unlock it without killing virtual machine and running it from scratch? I assume this approach could also damage the data if the project was any more advanced then it currently is...

There must be an intelligent way to resolve this situation instead of renaming the database after every exception that is not caught.

**main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
//      System.out.println("Starting server - press enter");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
//      s.nextLine();
        DBserver serv = new DBserver(name, port);
        serv.start();
        System.out.println("started - hit enter to insert data");
        s.nextLine();
        Connection con = null;

        try{
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"); //loads db driver
            waitt("connect...");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:hsqldb:" + name, "sa", "");
            waitt("drop...");
            try{
                con.prepareStatement("drop table testtable;").execute();
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.err.println("Failed to drop... exception");
            }
            waitt("create table...");
            con.prepareStatement("create table testtable (id INTEGER, " +
                                    "name VARCHAR);").execute();
            waitt("query table...");
            ResultSet rs = con.prepareStatement("select * from testtable;").executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            System.out.println("ID = " + rs.getInt(1) + " Name=" + rs.getString(2));

        } finally {
            if (con != null) con.close();
        }

        waitt("finish...");
        serv.stop();
        serv.close();
        System.out.println("Finished - bye");

    }
```

**DBserver.java**

```
public class DBserver {

    private String name = "noname";
    private int port = 14643;
    private Server serv = null;

    public DBserver(){
        serv = this.create();
    }

    public DBserver(String name, int port){
        this.name = name;
        this.port = port;
        serv = this.create();
    }

    public Server create(){
          Server server=new Server();
          server.setDatabaseName(0,this.name);
          server.setDatabasePath(0,"file:" + this.name);
          server.setPort(this.port);
          server.setSilent(true);
          server.setLogWriter(null);
          return server;
        }

    public int start(){
        if (this.serv != null) return this.serv.start();
        else return -1;
    }

    public int stop(){
        if (this.serv != null) return this.serv.stop();
        else return -1;
    }

    public int close(){
        if (this.serv != null) {
            this.serv.shutdown();
            return 1;
        }
        else return -1;
    }

    public String getName(){ return this.name;}
    public int getPort(){return this.port;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The database is opened by the Server class which is started in a separate thread. You can execute the SHUTDOWN command as SQL or alternatively use server.shutdown() to shut it down and release the .lock file.

Note you are connecting to the database files directly as well as starting a server. Some programs are written like this this to allow external access. The database is shutdown only if you perform SHUTDOWN as SQL.

The server is online so long as the JVM is active and the database has not been SHUTDOWN.

Comment: Since the main program crashed/got an unhandled exception the server id is lost - but that means the database can still be used and operated if I just restart the client part? So if I make a routine to check if the database is running, I could just restart my program without any issues?